# Enable ETW Events for ASP.Net Web Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, etw

## Problem

I have as ASP.NET application, and I'd like to capture ETW events for a web request call.  I'm looking for events to fire as the web request is handled so I can match that activity up with CPU activity.  The **trouble** is that I cannot get such data despite tweaking various logging knobs.

## Expectation

Logging for the ASP.NET provider (aff081fe-0247-4275-9c4e-021f3dc1da35) as well as other interesting sounding IIS providers (e.g. IIS Perf Counters - 90303b54-419d-4081-a683-6dbcb532f261, IIS W3SVC - 05448e22-93de-4a7a-bba5-92e27486a8be, others are in the code snippet below) would be emitted when enabled via a WPRP file.

## Actual

Only Microsoft-Windows-IIS-Logging and Microsoft-Windows-WinHttp events are received.

## Versions

- OS:  Windows Server 2016, ver 1607
- IIS: 10.0
- ASP.NET: (system.web.mvc) 5.02.30128.0

## Things Tried

### #1 WPRP File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WindowsPerformanceRecorder Version="1.0">
  <Profiles>
    <EventCollector Id="EventCollector_OSWebServer" Name="GeneralOSWebServer">
      <BufferSize Value="1024" />
      <Buffers Value="400" />
    </EventCollector>

    <!-- NO EVENTS EMITTED -->
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_Asp_Net" Name="aff081fe-0247-4275-9c4e-021f3dc1da35" />
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_IIS_W3SVC" Name="05448e22-93de-4a7a-bba5-92e27486a8be" />
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_IIS_PerfCounters" Name="90303b54-419d-4081-a683-6dbcb532f261" />
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_IIS_AppHostSvc" Name="cac10856-9223-48fe-96ba-2a772274fb53" />
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_Http_Web" Name="41877cb4-11fc-4188-b590-712c143c881d" />
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_Http_Svc" Name="dd5ef90a-6398-47a4-ad34-4dcecdef795f" />

    <!-- EVENTS EMITTED -->
    <!-- enabled by turning etw logging via IIS Manager -->
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_IIS_Logging" Name="7e8ad27f-b271-4ea2-a783-a47bde29143b" />
    <!-- Enabled by adding <httpTracing /> element to web.config 
         Correction, might have just not had any events firing -->
    <EventProvider Id="EventProvider_Http_Win" Name="7d44233d-3055-4b9c-ba64-0d47ca40a232" />

    <Profile Id="GeneralOSWebServer.Verbose.File" Name="GeneralOSWebServer" Description="OS Events relevant to web server operation" LoggingMode="File" DetailLevel="Verbose">
      <Collectors>
        <EventCollectorId Value="EventCollector_OSWebServer">
          <EventProviders>
            <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_Asp_Net" />
            <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_IIS_W3SVC" />
                  <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_IIS_Logging" />
                  <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_IIS_PerfCounters" />
                  <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_IIS_AppHostSvc" />
                  <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_Http_Web" />
                  <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_Http_Win" />
                  <EventProviderId Value="EventProvider_Http_Svc" />
          </EventProviders>
        </EventCollectorId>
      </Collectors>
    </Profile>
    <Profile Id="GeneralOSWebServer.Verbose.Memory" Name="GeneralOSWebServer" Description="OS Events relevant to web server operation (memory)" Base="GeneralOSWebServer.Verbose.File" LoggingMode="Memory" DetailLevel="Verbose" />
  </Profiles>
</WindowsPerformanceRecorder>
```

- I've only been able to get IIS logging and http_win logging (provider ids 7e8ad27... & 7d4423...) events to be emitted when exercising the application.  IIS logging events are the only ones of much interest, but they are summary logs that occur after the web request is finished, whereas I'm looking for events to occur for the various stages of the web request life cycle **AS they happen**.

### #2 Enabled IIS logging

Followed these instructions:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/logging-to-etw-in-iis-85

### #3 Enabled http trace logging in web.config

Followed these instructions:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httptracing/

## Closing

Any help, hints or wild guesses would be greatly appreciated, thanks.